# Sending post request to shapeshift

Tags: contract-development, shapeshift

Using the example pose request from https://info.shapeshift.io/api#api-7 :

```
url:  shapeshift.io/shift
method: POST
data type: JSON
data required:
withdrawal     = the address for resulting coin to be sent to
pair       = what coins are being exchanged in the form [input coin]_[output coin]  ie btc_ltc
returnAddress  = (Optional) address to return deposit to if anything goes wrong with exchange
destTag    = (Optional) Destination tag that you want appended to a Ripple payment to you
rsAddress  = (Optional) For new NXT accounts to be funded, you supply this on NXT payment to you
apiKey     = (Optional) Your affiliate PUBLIC KEY, for volume tracking, affiliate payments, split-shifts, etc...

example data: {"withdrawal":"AAAAAAAAAAAAA", "pair":"btc_ltc", returnAddress:"BBBBBBBBBBB"}

Success Output:
    {
        deposit: [Deposit Address (or memo field if input coin is BTS / BITUSD)],
        depositType: [Deposit Type (input coin symbol)],
        withdrawal: [Withdrawal Address], //-- will match address submitted in post
        withdrawalType: [Withdrawal Type (output coin symbol)],
        public: [NXT RS-Address pubkey (if input coin is NXT)],
        xrpDestTag : [xrpDestTag (if input coin is XRP)],
        apiPubKey: [public API attached to this shift, if one was given]
    }
```

I send post request to :

```
 shapeshift.io/shift
```

with parameters

```
{"withdrawal":"AAAAAAAAAAAAA", "pair":"btc_ltc", returnAddress:"BBBBBBBBBBB"}
```

But do not receive a response.

Is my post format correct ?

Comment: I am using cURL and I get the error: {"error":"No Withdrawal Address Specified"} no matter what I do. There are no obvious errors in the code. What are my options if cURL is always going to give this error?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10839)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake in the documentation. The example POST string is no valid JSON `"returnAddress"` needs to be enquoted.

Try:

```
 $ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"withdrawal":"LZwZMi6i9suK1wzFaw1NHqcYLcLGAo1Fs3", "pair":"btc_ltc", "returnAddress":"1HpnZkPHDMdiezuxT1sbKgLgBGTb1Q7eEP"}' https://shapeshift.io/shift
```

Gives me the following response:

```
{"orderId":"fca7e528-e0ba-4b4e-a43b-237d8a81b2a6","deposit":"1Khh3ndcoKBDsKe2gvmK9f2M1TpimXWWXw","depositType":"BTC","withdrawal":"LZwZMi6i9suK1wzFaw1NHqcYLcLGAo1Fs3","withdrawalType":"LTC","public":null,"apiPubKey":"shapeshift","returnAddress":"1HpnZkPHDMdiezuxT1sbKgLgBGTb1Q7eEP","returnAddressType":"BTC"}
```

You did not state how you query the API, if you use `curl` you will get always an error string back, whatever you do, e.g.,

```
{"error":"No Withdrawal Address Specified"}
```